# How can I make Instagram photos shared to Facebook visible to my friends by default?

Tags: facebook, sharing, instagram

When I share photos from Instagram to Facebook (using the Instagram app on iOS), by default they get "Only Me" sharing visibility:

[image]

That doesn't seem very useful to me - I'd rather my friends saw them. In fact, [Instagram's help page says that is what is supposed to happen](https://help.instagram.com/help/instagram/530864983594850).

How can I fix this? How can I make these photos visible to my friends by default?

Comment: As this is a question about an iOS app rather than a web app, this question would be better off at [apple.se].

Comment: I don't really agree; although the source of the share is from an iOS app, I suspect the answer lies in Facebook.com privacy settings. But it's obviously hard to tell without an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As **Andrew Ferrier** stated in the comments to the question, this is indeed a part of Facebook's privacy settings. Here is how you set it to share to "Friends" by default:

1. Go to your **Facebook.com**.
2. Find the page to edit your Instagram settings.

   - this should be on **YourLinkToTimelinePage/app_instapp**
   - or you should be able to find it at https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications
   - or in the timeline menu under your profile picture, find it in **More**
3. Change your **App visibility and post audience** setting to **Friends**

   This setting controls who on Facebook can see that you use this app. It also allows you to choose the audience for posts the app makes on your behalf.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I could kiss you! Why on Earth it's that difficult, I can only guess

Comment: Personally, I couldn't find Instagram in Settings > Apps, but I did find it in the "More" drop-down menu.

Comment: 3rd bullet point worked perfectly.

Comment: 3rd bullet point for me as well. **More->Instagram(dropdown item)->Manage(pencil icon on the right in the instagram section)**